# SQLite adding columns in row in query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to do a little bit of math in in a sqlite call. I have two columns that I want to add their value then check to see if they are less than a value that I input.

```
    c = self.db.cursor()
    c.execute("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION");
    c.execute("SELECT ID as id,task FROM tube WHERE state=0 OR (state=1 & ts+ttr<? ) ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1", (time.time(),))
    task = c.fetchone()
    print task
    if task != None:
        ts = time.time();
        c.execute("UPDATE tube SET state=1,ts=? WHERE ID=?", (ts, task['id']))
        task['ts'] = ts
    else:
        task = None

    self.db.commit()
    return task
```

From what I can tell its not doing this operation. It still returns a row but not based on the logic I am providing.

Comment: you should post more python code

Comment: @FoxMaSk added more code for u

Comment: do you use `Bottle` or `Flask` ? to try to understand what could be returned by `c.fetchone()` and then if it's possible to modify it on the fly by adding ts to it.

Comment: @FoxMaSk i am not use ethier just torando

Comment: so what's look like the `def fetchone()` ? as I dont see yet a known ORM that provides this function

Comment: @FoxMaSk It isn't ORM. It just returns one row of the SQL result.
Also, you may want to use the `NOW()` SQL function or whatever it is called in sqlite instead of `time.time()`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo ok ; i saw [pep 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) about that.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I needed return the value of time.time() if the query changes a record other wise i would use NOW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the bitwise and operator `&` where you probably want a logical `AND`.

The bitwise operators have higher precedence that the comparisons (`=`, `<`), while the logical ones have lower. Therefore `state=1 & ts+ttr<?` is very different from `state=1 AND ts+ttr<?`

Comment: I think i see what you mean Its been while since i wrote sql